# ULS Logs are not created in LOGS folder

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using SHAREPOINT 2010 , when i run different sharepoint application i can not see any log files at

**C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS**

I checked in **CA -> Monitoring -> Configure Diagnostic Logging** , all things are fine over there.

I run other ULSLOGVIEWER.EXE as well to see but i could not find it..

before some days logs were created successfully at above location.

pls help me...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account running the "SharePoint 2010 Tracing" service is part of the "Performance Log Users" local security group.

Answer (score 0):

Change log file location in "Configure Diagnostics Logging" to some other folder, then change it back to **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS**